# Desejo que ao receber um e-mail depois que se passa 24hrs ele mostra a data e nao o tempo atrás conforme a imagem

Tags: php, data

Estou utilizando o : [briannesbitt/Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)

Utilizo este código para renderizar o que desejo

```
<?= \Carbon\Carbon::create($mail->created_at)->locale('pt')->diffForHumans(); ?> atrás
```

O mesmo imprime igual a imagem abaixo:

[image: Gerenciador de e-mail]

Oque desejo é o seguinte: Depois de 24 horas que o e-mail chegar na caixa de entrada, o mesmo imprimir a data de criação em vez de "há 1 dia atrás" ou "há 1semana atrás" no caso o "há 1 hora atrás" esta correto, e o que consta "há 1 semana atrás", deveria ser a data de criação exemplo 17/02/2021.

Comment: Faz um `if`. Se for menor que 24h, você mostra o `diffForHumans`, caso contrário mostra a data formatada.

Comment: Obrigado, nossa eu sou novato com datas, to aprendendo, agora que descobri sobre o Carbon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só implementar uma condição que verifica se a diferença é maior que 24h. Algo assim:

```php
$diff = \Carbon\Carbon::create($mail->created_at)->locale('pt');

if ($diff->diffInHours() > 24) {
  echo $diff->format("d/m/Y H:i:s");
} else {
  echo $diff->diffForHumans();
}
```

Comment: obrigado ficou do jeito que eu queria